# How can I test a scala function?

Tags: scala, function, return-value

I started learning scala and in order to learn, I want to play with some functions. However, I dont know how to make a functions return value appear on the console. I am using sbt.

I tried with return and Console.println, I guess I dont use it right.

for example:

```
def func(ls: List[Boolean]): Boolean = ls match 
    {
      case Nil => false
      case l::ls => l != func(ls)
    }
```

how do I see what this function returns?

Comment: `print("aaa")` will output `aaa` to console.

Comment: that is obvious. but this function returns a Boolean, true or false. how do I see if it returns true or false?

Comment: `print` works fine with `Boolean`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org) is an online interactive playground for Scala  and is a quick way to get started. For example, pasting the following in the editor and pressing `Save` button

```
def func(ls: List[Boolean]): Boolean = ls match {
  case Nil => false
  case l::ls => l != func(ls)
}

func(List(true, false, true))
```

should evaluate `func` and show the result inline like so

```
func(List(true, false, true)) // false: Boolean
```

Also try `println(func(List(true, false, true)))`

Another way of testing the expected result without having to print it is to use assertions like so

```
assert(func(List(true, false, true)) == false)
```

To convert above assertion to a real unit test we could instantiate an application from [Scala Giter8 template](https://github.com/scala/scala-seed.g8) like so

```
sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8
```

which setups all the furniture necessary to quickly run and test applications. Then add `func` to `src/main/scala/example/Hello.scala` like so

```
object Hello extends App {
  def func(ls: List[Boolean]): Boolean = ls match {
    case Nil => false
    case l::ls => l != func(ls)
  }
}
```

and add corresponding unit tests to `src/test/scala/example/HelloSpec.scala` like so

```
class HelloSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "func" should "return false on List(true, false, true)" in {
    Hello.func(List(true, false, true)) shouldEqual false
  }

  it should "return false on empty list" in {
    Hello.func(List()) shouldEqual false
  }

  // add further tests here
}
```

Now executing `sbt test` should output

```
[info] HelloSpec:
[info] func
[info] - should return false on List(true, false, true)
[info] - should return false on empty list
[info] Run completed in 127 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 2
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 2, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```scala
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def func(ls: List[Boolean]): Boolean = ls match
      {
        case Nil => false
        case l::ls => l != func(ls)
      }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

func: (ls: List[Boolean])Boolean

scala> func(List(true, false, true))
res0: Boolean = false
```